# TortoiseHG to Bitbucket - Sub-Repository setup in TortoiseHg

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, bitbucket

I originally posted this question and found that Bitbucket does not support nested sub repos (**CORRECTION:** Bitbucket was not the problem at all...potentially bad information or misunderstood what they meant by nested subrepo) . I had to arrange them in Tortoise as sibling Repos. [Mercurial to Bitbucket - Subrepository - Repository is unrelated error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13886914/mercurial-to-bitbucket-subrepository-repository-is-unrelated-error)

My problem now is that TortoiseHg/Mercurial does not pick up the changes in my subrepos.

My directory structure looks like this: (sibling and not child folders)

```
MainRepo (to hold all subrepos)
SubRepo1 (main project)
SubRepo2 (class library)
SubRepo3 (class library)
```

etc...

In my .hgsub file, i have the following

```
SubRepo1 = ../SubRepo1
SubRepo2 = ../SubRepo2
SubRepo3 = ../SubRepo3
```

etc...

My problem is that the MainRepo does not detect any of the changes in my SubRepo. I noticed that there is now a folder for in the MainRepo folder for each of my subrepos. I suspect TortoiseHg is looking in there for changes...and not my ../SubRepoX folder.

Can anyone guide me to a working SubRepository scenario for TortoiseHg pushing to Bitbucket

**UPDATE:** See this link for the resolution to my subrepo problem. [Recommended way to coordinate versions of multiple dependent mercurial repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934437/recommended-way-to-coordinate-versions-of-multiple-dependent-mercurial-repositor)

Answer (score 2):

The subrepo directory reference should be relative to the location of the .hgsub file.

Therefore, you should have = ./SubRepo rather than ../SubRepo.

Here's the [official docs](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository). They're not too hard to read.

Comment: Thank you...I was hopeful that your simple change would have done the trick. Unfortunately, that doesn't help in the TortoiseHg world. I formatted the .hgsub file to use a static path, and the same result occurs. It appears to not be a relative path issue, but an issue that Tortoise SubRepos and Bitbucket do not get along. Perhaps someone with TortoiseHg SubRepo and Bitbucket experience can offer assistance.

Comment: I successfully used TortoiseHG, subrepos and Bitbucket, so I know it did work (was about 4 months ago). I don't think bitbucket should impact the result. It's just an HG server, so shouldn't be part of the issue.   Do you see the changes ok from the command-line, but not from tortoisehg? Is that the issue? THG, when looking at the main repo, will show that a subrepo has changed in the diff view, but won't show the actual changes (IIRC). The subrepo will be a link which will open the subrepo in a new tab. We CAN get this working. Will check tonight for more config details.

Comment: Hello @Mikezx6r, turns out that I went back to a nested subrepo structure. When adding subrepos via TortoiseHg, they formatted the .hgsub file like this   subrepo = subrepo   ... which was intuitive to me. But actually, it needed to be     subrepo = ../subrepo   ... That did the trick for me. I tried so many different variations, but this explains my resolution better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13934437/recommended-way-to-coordinate-versions-of-multiple-dependent-mercurial-repositor

Comment: Glad you were able to resolve it. I hadn't used TortoiseHG to define my subrepos, so perhaps that's why I didn't have issues.